# Countable sets Proof of Product of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How can i proove that |$N$| =
|$N^n$|

i can proove that for NxN but cant figure out how to show that for any product

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First show that $\mathbb{N}^2 \simeq \mathbb{N}$, then by induction you get your result. To do so, you can count elements of $\mathbb{N}^2$ with the (finite) slices $S_n\{(p,q) \in \mathbb{N}^2 \, |\, p + q = n\} = \{(k,n-k), \, k \in \{ 0, \dots, n\}\}$. Here is what the count looks like:
$$(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (0,2), (1,1), (2,0), (0,3), (1,2), (2,1), (3,0), (0,4), \dots$$

For the induction, just use that $\mathbb{N}^{n+1} = \mathbb{N}^n \times \mathbb{N} \simeq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \simeq \mathbb{N}.$

Ultimately with a Cantor diagonal extraction you can even show that for $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a family of countable set,
$$A = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n$$
is countable.

Since you asked for explicit bijection, there are two ways to do so:

1. The first is a generalization of the bijection I suggested for $\mathbb{N}^2$: count with slices that are orthogonal to the line $\{(x,\dots,x) \in \mathbb{R}^n, x \in \mathbb{R}\}$
   $$S_k = \{(i_1,\dots,i_n) \in \mathbb{N}^n \, |\, i_1 + \cdots + i_n = k\} $$
   On each slice you can define an order: for example the lexicographical order (like alphabetical but for tuples) for example $(2,5) > (1,54)$ and $(2,5) > (2,3)$. Just count the first slice with this order, then the second etc...
2. The second is more geometric: just partition you spaces with cubes faces: the $n$th slice is given by all elements which are on the face of the cube of side $=n$. Then define an order and count them...

Comment: "Cantor diagonal extraction" gives only 21 results in Google. Please, don't use something that can be that confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have proved that $$|\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{N}|,$$ now suppose that for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have that $$|\mathbb{N}^n|=|\mathbb{N}|,$$ so $$|\mathbb{N}^{n+1}|=|\mathbb{N}^n\times \mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{N}|.$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.